# Would an old crappy Mac Mini with 1gb RAM be Sufficient to program iphone apps on?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I am considering buying an old mac  mini for about 100 dollars to program iphone apps on. This would be its only purpose. Is this sufficient hardware? It has only 1gb ram and only 1.4ghz processor.

Comment: If this mini is so old that it won't run Xcode 5.1 (requires Mountain Lion or Mavericks) then absolutely not.

Comment: Oh - and running Xcode without 16 GB of RAM, while possible, is less pleasant than it needs to be. I'd say 4 GB is an absolute minimum.

Comment: This shouldn't of been closed.  It is not opinion based at all.

Comment: @matt - I have mac mini late 2012 i5 2.5GHz , 4 GB RAM(2/2) ...I am planning to upgrade RAM since I am having hard time working with Xcode 7 and el Capitan. Will 8 GB (4/4) will be enough or I should go it 16 GB(8/8)?
 If this is not the platform to ask this kind of question,where can i ask?

Answer (score 1):

No.

In case that wasn't clear, I'll elaborate.

If it has 1GB of RAM that means it's old and most likely won't even run the latest version of Xcode like @matt mentioned. Even if it does, with 1 GB of RAM you'll have a hard time even getting it to link, let alone build and run it.

Even if you beat all odds and get it to work, the experience will be awful, and you'll spend WAY to much time doing trivial things (like pulling your hair out). OS X by itself will use almost of your memory.

So don't do it. Just buy the better hardware. :)

Comment: I just feel bad buying a new mac when I already having a perfectly functioning Desktop and Laptop. :(

Comment: I was in the same boat for a while, until I finally just paid the bucks and got a new 8GB Mac Mini, and although that works, it actually was still pretty annoying to work with, and now I use the a 16GB Macbook Pro, which works great (though perhaps overly pricy if you only want to do iOS applications). Definitely buy a new/refurbished 4+ GB Mini if you're going that route.

Comment: In addition, if it's really a 1.4GHz, that means it's a PowerPC (the slowest Intel mini made was 1.5GHz).   You need to have at least a Core 2 processor to run Mavericks, and you need to run at least 10.8 in order to run Xcode 5.1, and you need to run Xcode 5.1 to submit to the AppStore as February 2014.  Basically, you need an Early 2009 Mini at the earliest (since all Minis that run 10.8 can also run 10.9).

Comment: I have mac mini late 2012 i5 2.5GHz , 4 GB RAM(2/2) ...I am planning to upgrade RAM since I am having hard time working with Xcode 7 and el Capitan. Will 8 GB (4/4) will be enough or I should go it 16 GB(8/8)?
If this is not the platform to ask this kind of question,where can i ask?

Comment: @the_UB 8GB is probably fine unless you run Virtual Machines while working with XCode.

Comment: Will 16GB(8/8) will work perfectly without a doubt? As I am thinking to upgrade it fully. Otherwise, I'll have to buy new mac.

Comment: @the_UB Yes, it should definitely work well.